# How to compare PM datetime in SQL to millisecond-based time?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, where-clause

I have a db field in this format:

```
 '2019/08/14 11:07:30 AM'
```

I'd like to compare to a dataframe cell from Python in this format:

```
'2020-04-06T13:40:23.000000000'
```

I've tried comparing these fields simply with a >= but get ORA-01681 literal does not match format string.

```
     AND s.time1 >= '2020-12-06T05:07:27.000'
     AND s.time2 >= '2020-12-06T05:07:27.000'
```

```
ORA-01681 literal does not match format string
```

The same happens when I try to cast them as datetime's except I get invalid datatype. What am I doing wrong and what is the right SQL expression to compare the two?

```
     AND CAST(s.time1 AS DATETIME) >= CAST('2020-12-06T05:07:27.000' AS DATETIME)
     AND CAST(s.time2 AS DATETIME) >= CAST('2020-12-06T05:07:27.000' AS DATETIME)
```

Obviously, it's ok if the milliseconds are rounded off since they're always 0 and the db time doesn't have that precision in this case.

Comment: Store dates using an appropriate data type, or don't bother with an RDBMS

Comment: You get Oracle errors with Oracle, not with MySQL.

Comment: *I have a db field in this format:* what is the datatype of the column? Dates and timestamps aren't stored with any display format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are storing your dates as Oracle `timestamp`s , then you just need to cast the literal values you are giving for comparisons. For this, you can use `to_timestamp()`:

```
and s.time1 >= to_timestamp('2020-12-06T05:07:27.000', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
```

If you have `date`s instead, then I would recommend triming the strings, then converting to `date`:

```
and s.time1 >= to_char(substr('2020-12-06T05:07:27.000', 1, 19),  'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to munge the query string, then you can express the logic as:

```
s.time1 > timestamp '2020-12-06T05:07:27.000'
```

However, I don't recommend that approach because you should be passing values in as parameters.

Instead, pass the value as a `date` or `timestamp` parameter for the comparison:

```
s.time1 > :time1
```

Or, if you must pass it as a string, parse it as a timestamp:

```
s.time1 > to_timestamp(:time1_str, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3')
```

Comment: That resulted in the following error:

DatabaseError: ('[UniqeServer] [Type:Oracle Managed] Invalid parameter binding',)